# One WebSite, Two IP Addresses, One SSL EV cert per IP

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5

I have a website in IIS and two different IP addresses on that server. I want to be able to assign a separate SSL certificate to the same site on IIS with the other IP address.

Something like this:

www.abc.com --> 1.1.1.1 --> SSL cert for ABC corp --> WebsiteX

www.xyz.com --> 1.1.1.2 --> SSL cert for XYZ corp --> WebsiteX

I've been fighting with this for a while now and it seems like WebsiteX can only have one SSL cert assigned to it. Is it possible to do what I'm proposing in IIS 7.5 or will I have to make another site in IIS for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have two separate bindings, one for each IP address. Each binding can have an independent certificate assigned.

Two bindings can exist on a single site definition in IIS.

That being said a SAN / UCC certificate will likely be the easier route to go.

That will only require one IP address and binding.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a SAN (Subject Alternative Name) certificate (also known as UCC) with both site names on it. Then bind that cert to the single site in IIS.

Comment: No. For SAN EV certificate, only one name is displayed on "the green bar" of a browser. Browser would display green "XYZ" on the site www.abc.com.

Comment: Good point, I missed that this was for an EV cert.